# How to Convert Swift String To C byte array and back to Swift String

Tags: swift, unicode-string

I'm trying to take a Swift string as a [UInt8] byte array, and then return the same byte array from C code and convert it back to the original Swift string.  I'm trying to preserve unicode (so no lossiness in conversions/manipulations).  I'm getting an error "Cannot convert value of type 'String.Encoding' to expected argument type 'UInt' on the conversion line in the decrypt function.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
    // function to encrypt a string with custom "C" code and encode the result into a hex string
func EncryptString( password: String, stringToEncrypt: String) ->String {

    var hexStr = ""

    // convert the String password into utf8 bytes
    let pw = password.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion:false)
    var passwordBytes : [UInt8] = Array(pw!)

    // convert the string to encrypt into utf8 bytes
    let bytes = stringToEncrypt.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion:false)
    var buf : [UInt8] = Array(bytes!)

    // encrypt the string to encrypt with the Unicode password (both are Unicode in Swift)
    encryptData(&passwordBytes, Int32(password.count), &buf, Int32(stringToEncrypt.count))

    // turn the now encrypted "stringToEncrypt" into two character hex values in a string
    for byte in buf {
        hexStr.append(String(format:"%2X", byte))
    }

    // return the encrypted hex encoded string to the caller...
    return hexStr
}


func DecryptString( password: String, hexStringToDecrypt: String) ->String {

    var decryptedStr = ""

    // convert the String password into utf8 bytes
    let pw = password.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion:false)
    var passwordBytes : [UInt8] = Array(pw!)

    // convert the string to encrypt into utf8 bytes
    let bytes = hexStringToDecrypt.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion:false)
    var buf : [UInt8] = Array(bytes!)

    // encrypt the string to encrypt with the Unicode password (both are Unicode in Swift)

    let bytecount = password.count
    decryptData(&passwordBytes, Int32(password.count), &buf, Int32(hexStringToDecrypt.count))
            // turn the now encrypted "hexStringToDecrypt" into int values here is where I get error: Cannot convert value of type 'String.Encoding' to expected argument type 'UInt'
    var unicode_str = NSString(bytes: buf, length: bytecount, encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding)

    // return the encrypted hex encoded string to the caller...
    return unicode_str
}
```

}

Comment: Point out the exact line causing the error. You have several lines trying to use `utf8`. And confirm that you are using Swift 3 or later.

Comment: Thank you! I am using Swift 4 and the current line of code giving the error is this: var unicode_str = NSString(bytes: buf, length: bytecount, encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding)

Comment: What exactly do you think a "C byte array" is?As far as I can tell a byte does not have a language association, it is simply 8-bits(these days). Nor is Swift "C".

Comment: With Swift 3/4 it is better to use the `Data` type in place of `UInt8`. Further `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding` is not the correct way to convert data to the String type, you need to specify the encoding type of the bytes and that is `utf8` because that is how the data was created.

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped me with this problem!  rmaddy's answer (now deleted?!) was actually the most helpful for my problem. I was just needing to cast differently as follows:  let unicode_str = NSString(bytes: buf, length: hexStringToDecrypt.count/2, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
      Please put back your original post rmaddy!  I really appreciate your help!  Thanks very much to zaph too!

Comment: @user6096790 `let unicode_str = NSString(bytes: buf, length: hexStringToDecrypt.count/2, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)` is not casting, it is a conversion.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, and thanks again for your help! :-)

Answer (score 3):

With Swift 3/4 it is better to use the `Data` type in place of `UInt8`.

Convert `String` to `Data`:

```
let dat = string.data(using:.utf8)
```

Convert `Data` to `String`:

```
let str = String(data:dat, encoding:.utf8)
```

Here is example encryption using `Data` in place of `UInt8`, this is not production code, it is missing error handling at a minimum.

```
func aesCBCEncrypt(data:Data, keyData:Data, ivData:Data) -> Data {
        let cryptLength = size_t(kCCBlockSizeAES128 + data.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
        var cryptData = Data(count:cryptLength)
        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptBytes in
            data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
                keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                    ivData.withUnsafeBytes {ivBytes in
                        CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),
                                CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),
                                CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding),
                                keyBytes, keyData.count,
                                ivBytes,
                                dataBytes, data.count,
                                cryptBytes, cryptLength,
                                &numBytesEncrypted)
                    }}}}

    cryptData.count = (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) ? numBytesEncrypted : 0

    return cryptData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! :-)